# Cannot connect to Centos 7 server (PAM)

Tags: centos, authentication, pam

After attempting to install a PAM module (my first), i've been having this issue. I ended up removing it because the module was broken which resulted in users not being able to access the system. Now is the case that I cant access it either, even after removing it.

How can I resolve this fault with PAM?

```
May  2 08:39:28 host sshd[14687]: Received disconnect from 00.000.00.000: 11: 
May  2 08:39:56 host sshd[14798]: PAM unable to dlopen(/lib64/security/pam_sepermit.so#015): /lib64/security/pam_sepermit.so#015: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
May  2 08:39:56 host sshd[14798]: PAM adding faulty module: /lib64/security/pam_sepermit.so#015
May  2 08:39:56 host sshd[14798]: PAM _pam_load_conf_file: unable to open /etc/pam.d/password-auth#015
May  2 08:39:56 host sshd[14798]: PAM unable to dlopen(/lib64/security/pam_nologin.so#015): /lib64/security/pam_nologin.so#015: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
May  2 08:39:56 host sshd[14798]: PAM adding faulty module: /lib64/security/pam_nologin.so#015
May  2 08:39:56 host sshd[14798]: PAM _pam_load_conf_file: unable to open /etc/pam.d/password-auth#015
May  2 08:39:56 host sshd[14798]: PAM _pam_load_conf_file: unable to open /etc/pam.d/password-auth#015
May  2 08:39:56 host sshd[14798]: PAM unable to dlopen(/lib64/security/pam_loginuid.so#015): /lib64/security/pam_loginuid.so#015: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
May  2 08:39:56 host sshd[14798]: PAM adding faulty module: /lib64/security/pam_loginuid.so#015
May  2 08:39:56 host sshd[14798]: PAM unable to dlopen(/lib64/security/pam_namespace.so#015): /lib64/security/pam_namespace.so#015: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
May  2 08:39:56 host sshd[14798]: PAM adding faulty module: /lib64/security/pam_namespace.so#015
May  2 08:39:56 host sshd[14798]: PAM _pam_load_conf_file: unable to open /etc/pam.d/password-auth#015
May  2 08:39:56 host sshd[14798]: Failed password for root from 00.000.00.000 port 55835 ssh2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every not found file name has a `#015` at its end. It isn't normal. Since octal number `015` is ASCII code for carriage return (CR), it seems to me you maybe edited some file inside `/etc/pam.d` in a way that turned it into DOS/Windows mode (CRLF at the end of the line instead of Linux/Unix LF-only end of line).

You need to boot into rescue mode and recover that broken file from backup. You can also get rid of `\015` character using `tr` command.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your great wisdom! I used nano to recreate a new file on my other linux server and used the file manager to paste in a replacement. Thank you :)